# Google Apps Script does not support searching emails from a circle

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

When I run following code in Google Apps Script it return 0 results. I still have sufficient quota to fetch results. So quota is not a problem here.

```
var threads = GmailApp.search("circle:following");
```

But the same query in original Gmail user interface works and returns a few emails.
What could be the possible cause of this ? Or my syntax is wrong ?

Comment: The syntax looks correct. I actually don't have any mail from contacts in circles to test this, but I get results with similar search terms, such as 'label:read'. Do you get results for other search queries such as when searching for labels? That might narrow down the issue.

Comment: How searching for labels can narrow down the search for emails from a circle ?

Comment: The suggestion was designed to check if the search function was just broken for this search specifically, or if it was all searches in the script. The answer provided indicates that its exclusively with that search however.

Comment: It works for other queries and breaks for this. Similar queries like circle:friends, circle:family etc. also does not work.

Comment: Yes, as per the answer you've accepted below, it's a known issue that wont be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is supported.

[Apps Script issue #2172](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2172)